# Identifier vs Strings in various popular databases

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

Is there an ANSI requirement on what should be used to quote a string vs a database identifier? It seems, at least for me, this is one of the most irritating parts of working with various databases -- namely, when to use backticks vs. single-quotes vs double-quotes. As an example, here are what it seems to be in Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, SqlServer, and SQLite:

[image]

For whatever reason, I prefer the MySQL way of being able to use both single- and double-quotes for strings (which many languages allow, such as python, javascript, etc.), and the backticks seems to work nicely as its so much less commonly used outside of annotating code-objects, and a table or column name often feels like a code object. Is there a standard suggestion on how to do this or is it entirely implementation dependent?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the ANSI requirement is that identifiers can't have spaces in them, and must start with a letter. So you're seeing how various DBMS's have relaxed those rules. If you want to be standards compliant, don't put embedded spaces. To me your code looks weird.

Comment: @AntC - you're absolutely right. I regard the need for double quotes in an identifier in SQL as some sort of a failure, too. I also avoid column names like `name`, `timestamp`, `date` like the plague, as they are reserved words, for example. But you might need to step away from the standard to satisfy a report requirement ....

Comment: @marcothesane what if you're just importing a json/csv/excel file though and the field has a space in it, that's the most common use case I've run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following is not the ANSI standard, it's at least the de-facto standard supported by most DBMS-s:

1. single quotes as string encloser for string literals
2. double quotes as string encloser for identifiers
3. if the string encloser exists within the string, double it; don't escape it with a backslash.

Quite some databases actually offer the `QUOTE_LITERAL()` and `QUOTE_IDENT()` functions that re-format strings exactly along those rules.

Example:

```
SELECT
     'The Restaurant called "Harry''s Bar" in Casablanca' -- string expression
 AS  "The Restaurant called ""Harry's Bar"" in Casablanca" -- column name
FROM dual;
-- out  The Restaurant called "Harry's Bar" in Casablanca 
-- out ---------------------------------------------------
-- out  The Restaurant called "Harry's Bar" in Casablanca
```

Comment: @mercothesane -- thanks, so if I understand correctly, Postgres and Oracle are standard, and then MySQL, SQLServer, and SQLite would be non-standard, correct?

Comment: That's my take on it. I know that SQL Server can actually support the rule I described, too. I tried the select above it in dbfiddle.co.uk with MySQL, successfully; with DB2, successfully; with PostgreSQL, successfully;  with SQLite, successfully; with SQL Server, successfully; with Yugabyte, with no result; it never came back ... So I would say it's the safest bet if you want to keep coding portable SQL

Comment: After a while, also Yugabyte came back - with the desired behaviour ...